# Required field validator gets fired on PostBack

Tags: javascript, asp.net, validation

There is a text-Area which is being validated by a Required field validator.

```
<textarea style="width: 380px" id="txtAdditonalEmail" runat="server" rows="5"></textarea>
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvAdditonal" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtAdditonalEmail" 
ErrorMessage="Atleast one additonal email is required"  ForeColor="Red" ValidationGroup="vldRequest"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
```

Also there is a fileupload control through which I am processing a file. The file upload haves a client Side OnChange event that is Validating the file extension and than doing a post back to read the file.

```
<asp:FileUpload ID="fluCsr" runat="server"  />
```

OnChange Javascript:

```
function ValidateFileUpload() {
            var fuData = document.getElementById('<%= fluCsr.ClientID %>');
            var FileUploadPath = fuData.value;
            var Extension = FileUploadPath.substring(FileUploadPath.lastIndexOf('.') + 1).toLowerCase();
            var lblMsg = $("#<%= lblMsg.ClientID %>");
            var btnRead = $("#<%=txtComments.ClientID %>");

            if (Extension != "txt" && Extension != "csr" && Extension != "pem") {
                if (lblMsg != null && btnRead != null) {
                    lblMsg.show();
                }
            }
            else {
                lblMsg.hide();
                this.$("#form1").submit();
            }

        }
```

After Post-back the file is read , But the required field validator is fired? how can this be stopped during this post-back?

Comment: What do you mean by `Required field validation is fired?` Do you mean that the validation is fired on the server side? Please share your server side code as well

Comment: it means that after the server side processing is complete , the required field message is shown in the browser....

Answer (score 0):

You have to write the custom validator to skip the server side validation.

Comment: You can easily extend the js function ValidateFileUpload() to include the check for the txtAdditonalEmail value.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.customvalidator.clientvalidationfunction.aspx  . It has a good example. You can easily omit the server side event handler to perform the check on the client side only.

Answer (score -2):

I think the problem is with `<textarea>` control. You need to use `<asp:TextBox TextMode="MultiLine">` control.

Here is a link on the reference...

[TextArea with Required Field Validator](http://www.velocityreviews.com/forums/t117928-how-to-validate-textarea.html)

Comment: it has nothing to do with text area... Even text box is having the same behavior.